# unable to compare password using firebase admin sdk in python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-admin-sdk

I am using admin-SDK of firebase in python

I have created a new user using the following code

```
user = auth.create_user(
        email=email,
        email_verified=False,
        password=password,
        display_name=name,
        disabled=False)
```

now I have created a function that takes *name* , _email id _ and *password* from the user and fetch user using it's email id and then checks if entered details are correct.

```
def check_user(self, name, email, password):  # fixme compare password
    user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
    if user.display_name == name and user.email == email:# add password comparision
        print('successful login')
        return True
    else:
        print('username or password incorrect')
    return False
```

I want to compare password entered with the password stored, but I am unable to compare as I can't access password, I can only access passwordHash using user.passwordHash and passwordSalt using user.passwordSalt.

is there any away I can find passwordHash or passwordSalt of password so I can compare the hashes.

Comment: If you're using Firebase Authentication, why are **you** trying to compare the password. That's Firebase Authentication's job, isn't it?

Comment: I am using firebase's admin-SDK, it has API's to create and fetch user data but no API is available for verification of the password, maybe I am missing it, please tell is there is an API for user login authentication in firebase's admin-SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual flow when using Firebase Authentication is that your users sign in with client-side code that uses a Firebase SDK directly. So in that case, 
Firebase itself would be performing the check whether the password is correct.

You **can** perform the check yourself, but you'll have to hash the plaintext password from the user in your code and then compare the stored and calculated hash values, essentially duplicating what Firebase already does. Firebase uses a [modified version of scrypt](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/scrypt/) to encrypt the passwords.

Comment: I am using firebase's admin-SDK, it has API's to create and fetch user data but no API is available for verification of the password, maybe I am missing it, please tell is there is an API for user login authentication in firebase's admin-SDK

Comment: The expected flow is that you let the Firebase client-side SDK send the password to the server to authenticate the user, instead of intercepting it yourself. You *can* still do the sign-up in your back-end, just not the sign-in. If you also want to do the sign-in yourself, you'll have to hash the password. See the second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called pyrebase. You can use it to mimic client in server. Simply use `sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)` once you initiate the pyrebase object.

GitHub url: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Admin SDK for python do not provide a way to compare password. However, there is a solution to confirm user authenticity.

This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398321/9681645