# Retrieving firebase data from ESP32 using micropython with authentication

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to connect to my realtime database from firebase using MicroPython in a ESP32, I was able to retrieve the data using ufirebase but only if the rules were public for reading and writing, now I have the following rules for the database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === <My uid>",
    ".write": "auth.uid === <My uid>"
  }
}
```

I am able to get my uid from my email and password that were registered in the authentication section in firebase using the micropython-firebase-auth library, but now I am not able of doing the request using ufirebase, I have tried doing a request with urequests in the following way:

```
import urequests

def get_data():
    response = urequests.get("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/<NODE>.json?auth=<My uid>")
    data = response.json()
    return data
```

But doing so, shows me the following message:
{'error': 'Permission denied'}

So I haven't been able of retrieving the information with the applied set of rules, the structure of the data is the following for all of the database.

[Example of data to retrieve from the realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGDlp.png)

Does anyone know how to do a request with micropython once you got the uid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't authentication by just passing your UID to the database. That'd be a huge security risk, as the [UID is not a secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret). You'll instead need to pass the user's ID token, which amongst others includes their UID, as shown in the documentation on [authenticating REST requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

If your microcontroller runs in a trusted environment, consider using the Admin SDK as shown here: [How to authenticate to Firebase using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676559/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-python).

If the device should be considered untrusted, there is no Firebase SDK for client-side Python to generate such a token though. Your options in that case are to either [call the REST API to authenticate the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth), or [use a 3rd party wrapper such as Pyrebase to sign in](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase)